# What is the password to update the previous elementary to Loki?

Tags: release-loki, security

I tried to upgrade straight to Loki but the installer asks for a password that I do not know. What is the password?

Comment: Questions and answers on this site should be posted in English.

Comment: This question would be more helpful if it elaborated when the password was needed, or a little more context. A screenshot or two could be useful

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, a password deve ser a de um utilizador root/administrador.

Segundo, a única forma de atualizar o Freya para o Loki é reinstalando o sistema. Alem disso, é impossível uma atualização completa para outra versão do elementaryOS ter só por volta de 300MB

---

First the password should be the one from a root/admin user.

Second the only way to upgrade from Freya to Loki is to reinstall. Besides, there is no way a complete elementary OS system upgrade only being around 300MB.

Answer (score -2):

You have to install from zero.

Comment: This answer would be better if you elaborated how/why